# Install permissions are not given to the Dynamics 365 admin

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365

We've got the [Dynamics 365 trial](https://portal.office.com/Signup?OfferId=bd569279-37f5-4f5c-99d0-425873bb9a4b&dl=DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1&Culture=en-us&Country=us&flight=AdminOnCustomization&ali=1) which is release on 1<sup>st</sup> November 2016 , the trial is in my name (hence I am the Admin).

To this, we're trying to add the [Project Service Automation](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/dynamics-365/mscrm.5b3e1c1b-5603-4f9c-8c95-be2fa53c7033) from [AppSource](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/). When we click on <kbd>Try</kbd>, it gives the below error:

> You do not have install permissions to the Dynamics 365 organization. Send a note to ask your admin to add the application, or [sign up for a free trial](https://portal.office.com/Signup?OfferId=bd569279-37f5-4f5c-99d0-425873bb9a4b&dl=DYN365_ENTERPRISE_PLAN1&Culture=en-us&Country=us&flight=AdminOnCustomization&ali=1) and add it to that.

Tried sending the request to the admin like this:

[image: Request to install application]

Which gives the below error:

[image: unexpected server error]

What is the fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue. But found a solution when I set my Global admin to system admin also. 
Go to your CRM account, Settings Tab -> Security -> Users -> Select your Global Admin user and Promote it to admin. Then try adding Project Service Automation.

[image: Reference Snapshot]

Cheers,
Sohil.

Comment: Perfect, this is what I needed. Thanks a loads man!

Answer (score 2):

How to add an app in Dynamics 365 after [permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40459754/2404470) are granted.

- Go to [Office 365 Admin center](https://portal.office.com/adminportal/home#/Settings/Apps)

[image: Office 365 Admin center]

- Click on the Dynamics 365

[image: Dynamics 365]

- Click on Manage your Dynamics 365 settings

[image: Manage your Dynamics 365 settings]

- Select the Dynamics 365 instance in concern

[image: Dynamics 365 instance]

- Click <kbd>Solutions</kbd>
- Click Install to install the packages as needed